# See the all uploaded images of a user as an admin

Tags: images, uploads

I can see the user uploded images in the media library. I click the name of a user to see all the images he/she uploaded but all is a blank page.

The url is like:
http://mysite.com/wp-admin/upload.php?author=$author_id

How can i solve this?

Comment: Please add [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

Comment: No error about it. It also not working in my newly installed wordpress. Maybe wordpress does not have that feature?

Comment: Sorry? Why would WordPress create the author specific link if it did not have that functionality? I just checked on a new-ish 3.6 and it works fine. Something on your site is broken. I can't tell what.

Comment: Then, i guess some plugins or a custom theme is breaking that functionality. I will update and look again.